# Returning image as byte array or create new api to serve those images?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a spring boot/angular app that uses multiple images.To save those images i created a File table:

```
@Entity
public class File {   
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Lob
    private Byte[] bytes;
}
```

I have an entity that uses these files:

```
public class DemoEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private File file;
}
```

My frontend needs to display all these DemoEntities objects on a single page.
Should i create an api that serves only files and on the DemoEntity class, instead of File field, add the link to that specific api?
If so, let's say that i want to display 100 demo entities.The client will make an http call for the whole list and then, for each member of that list, another call to get the image.Can this affect the performance of an app?
What is the best way to handle images in a web app?

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with this issue once when I assisted on a major site rebuild for [Alternative Apparel](https://www.alternativeapparel.com/) back in 2010. We had to serve up an entire page of thumbnail images which were taking an unacceptably long time to load. I came up with an algorithm for making it load much faster, which worked great apart from the fact that it was quite complex, requiring annoyingly large amounts of Java code, complex data structures, etc. As proud as I was once I got this whole contrivance to make an entire page of thumbnails load in the blink of an eye as opposed to like ten seconds, I soon discovered another solution that worked just as well, but was far less complex -- simple [HTTP caching](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching).